# Constrain drawableLeft and drawableRight's height to TextView's height

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I have the following `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Updating Rates" />
```

And the result is this:

[image]

How do I make the loading circle drawable constrain proportionally so its height matches the height of the text?

Also, if possible, I would like to add some spacing between the text and the image.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make the `loading` smaller just make the images smaller.

Or use `RelativeLayout` and put the loading in an `ImageView` and scale it.

Or you can add padding between the drawables and the text using [`android:drawablePadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding) (or [`setCompoundDrawablePadding()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding(int))):

```
android:drawablePadding="3dp"
```

Comment: @offset resize the images (Photoshop, GIMP, online tools, ...etc)

Comment: That's what I said, I reduced the image and it solved my problem.

Comment: " just make the images smaller" so how small for compatibility +11k devices?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns the scaled images should go into the various scaled drawable folders drawable-mdpi for 160dpi, drawable-xhdpi for 320 dpi, etc.  For all the sizes see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Answer (score 8):

I think I found the solution, but a bit late

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_vit);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5),(int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
Button btn = findViewbyId(R.id.yourbtnID);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ravi's solution worked for me, but on some devices drawable was disappearing. Fixed this by removing the scaling.

```
    int bound = (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, bound, bound);
    b.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Better solution will to create a XML in drawable folder and add the image to this XML, and maintain scaleType as "fitXY". Now you can make this XML as the drawableLeft.

Comment: Can you add more detail? Maybe a sample XML File?

Comment: I tried this and it does not work.  You can't set the size of a <bitmap> via XML in the drawable folder.  The scaleType="fitXY" applies to ImageViews not drawables..   I went with scaling the images and putting them into the various drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi folders instead.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to declare two separate views imageview and textview, and set them accordingly

Comment: Yea but sometimes drawableRight is needed inside the TextView for click listeners (like a calendar picker icon).  So setting them separately will be a problem.

Comment: Put them in a LinearLayout and set the click on the Layout. Problem solved!