# How to set an image's width and height when it's set in drawableLeft

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-radiobutton

I set an image to a RadioButton's drawableLeft, but it's to big. I want to set the image's height, width and scaleType in order to let it looks ok, just like in an ImageView:

```
android:layout_width="30dip"
android:layout_height="30dip"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

But i find there are no attributions for image when it's set in drawableLeft.

Is there any ways to solve this.

Is it possible to handle this in XML ?

Comment: check out this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767726/constrain-drawableleft-drawablerights-height-to-textviews-height

Comment: what do you want to change height of radio button or your image?

Comment: You can use drawable padding attribute also.

Comment: @Abhishek I just want to change the size of the image, not the radio button.

Comment: @EyadMhanna drawable padding can change the size.

Comment: @wojciech_maciejewski thank u, it seems the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
radioButton.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @L.Swifter For that you have to create your own custom view.. [Go to this link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You will not get all the proporties of an `ImageView` in `drawableLeft`.
You have to use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) or [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) with `ImageView` and `RadioButton` for this purpose

You can use `android:drawablePadding` to get padding between the text and the drawable

Comment: you mean there is no way to solve this without a ViewGroup ?